# Opencv: cv2.findContours modifies image that has already been plotted?

Tags: opencv, python-2.7

I'm encountering a odd behaviour and while I can work around it I would like to know why this is.

When I use cv2.findContours it modifies the original image, even if I haven't passed it to the function. Here is a minimal example where the picture can be found [here](http://www.negative-probability.net23.net/a.jpg).

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import cv2

img =cv2.imread('a.jpg',0)
a1=plt.subplot(121)
plt.imshow(img, cmap='Greys')

ret, thresh = cv2.threshold(img,57,255,cv2.THRESH_BINARY)

a1=plt.subplot(122)
plt.imshow(thresh, cmap='Greys')
plt.show()

temp=thresh
del thresh

contours, hierarchy = cv2.findContours(temp,cv2.RETR_TREE,cv2.CHAIN_APPROX_SIMPLE)
```

When I comment out the line with cv2.findContours it works fine. Why is that?

Comment: In your code, both temp and thresh are same object. temp is just a different view of thresh, not a copy. put `temp=thresh.copy()`. It will solve the issue.

Comment: Thank you, that makes it work! But the modification should happen after I have plotted it, right? Why does it change the plot?

Comment: I guess .imshow needs some time and might happen in a background thread, so changing the image while plotting might change the (unfinished) plot. Can you add a `waitKey(30)` behind the imshow or the python equivalent for waitKey (don't know python syntax)?

Comment: @Micka The wait doesn't make any difference. However, I tried it via command line and there it worked correctly, so it has to do with the fact that I was using Spyder IDE

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It happens because `temp` *is* `thresh`.
In python when you make an assignment like that you are not coping the object, you are just making a new reference.
Take a look at `copy` module to achieve your goal.

Comment: Thank you, that makes it work! But the modification should happen after I have plotted it, right? Why does it change the plot?

Comment: I don't know. The plot doesn't change for me, at least using the code that you have pasted.

Comment: Intresting, so it probably has something to do with my enviroment. Thanks for the help!